# Php не выводит сообщение после отправки письма из формы

Tags: php, email, form

Есть стандартная форма для отправки почты.

```html
<form action="mail/contact_me.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" required/>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required/>
<input type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон" required/>
<textarea name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Сообщение" required></textarea>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Все переменные расписаны и обработаны - trim и тд.
php выглядит следующим образом:

```php
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$mess = $_POST["message"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];

$name = htmlspecialchars($name);
$email = htmlspecialchars($email);
$mess = htmlspecialchars($mess);
$phone = htmlspecialchars($phone);

$name = urldecode($name);
$email = urldecode($email);
$mess = urldecode($mess);
$phone = urldecode($phone);

$name = trim($name);
$email = trim($email);
$mess = trim($mess);
$phone = trim($phone);

mail("pochta122@lenta.ru", "Заявка с сайта", "Имя: " . "$name" . "\n" . "Телефон: " . "$phone" . "\n" . "E-mail: " . "$email" . "\n\n" . "Сообщение: " . "\n" . "$mess");
if (mail == TRUE) {
    echo "Заявка отправлена.";
} else {
    echo "Ошибка отправки.";
}
?>
```

Почему не выводится сообщение об отправки?
Письмо при этом отправляется и приходит на почту!

Comment: Потому что синтаксическая ошибка, включите вывод ошибок, или смотрите в фаил лога

Comment: Синтаксическая ошибка? А где она возникает?

Comment: Смотрите в логах, в примере нет ковычек где `pochta@ya.ru, title`

Comment: если хотя бы в одной строке кода допущена синтаксическая ошибка, то письмо не отправляется. в коде кавычки есть. выложил весь код..

Comment: может просто буфер где то перехватывается. В любом случае этот код вроде рабочий.

Comment: Или может где скобка потеряна `{}` по этому их рекомендуют всегда использовать

Comment: пробовал. результат такой же. письмо доходит, текст не выводится.

Comment: Пытаюсь вставить alert, тоже не работает.

Comment: `die('здесь');` попробуйте

Comment: Ввёл этот код и запустил. Напечатало "Произошла ошибка при отправке сообщения.". С синтаксисом всё нормально. Я думаю, функция mail() отключена на хостинге

Comment: странно. у меня письмо приходит и сообщение об ошибке не выводится((

Answer (score 0):

Функция `mail()` вернёт `TRUE` или `FALSE`, поэтому необходимо проверить с условием `mail(...) === true`

---

даже если он возвращает true, это не означает, что сообщение будет отправлено. Все, что делает mail (), это добавляет сообщение в очередь (используя sendmail или что - то другое, что вы установили в `php.ini`.

Нет надежного способа проверить, было ли сообщение отправлено на php. Поэтому Вам наверно придется просмотреть журналы почтового сервера.

Comment: Дело явно не в этом

Comment: почему вы так думаете?

Comment: Ну потому что хоть одна ветка ИФа сработала бы, если б mail() вернула бы хоть что-нибудь. В php неявное преобразование к булевому типу, нет тут смысла в ===

Comment: Ну и запускал я этот код у тебя. Отрабатывает

Comment: Хорош понял ваш ответ)) ну вообщем я дополнил свой ответ))

Comment: письмо приходит на почту. просто нет вывода сообщения об отправки. и посетитель сайта не понимает отправил он письмо или нет.

Comment: тогда Можете посмотреть этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/9308373

Comment: int(8) string(23) "Undefined index: submit" string(50) .. получил такую ошибку после добавления в скрипт error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");

Comment: int(8) string(47) "Use of undefined constant mail - assumed 'mail'" string(50).... вот ещё такую получил.. письмо при этом приходит на почту..

Comment: Вы чего-то не договариваете :) Явно не весь текст скрипта привели :)

Comment: перезалил весь код вместе с формой...

Comment: Ну вот и ошибка!!! if (mail == TRUE)  mail не определена как константа, не переменная, не функция. Нужно было результат функции mail() записать в переменную и её в ИФ поставить

Comment: разобрался!!) шла отсылка на файл contact.js ..Удалил его и сообщение об отправки вывелось на другой странице contact_me.php ..теперь вопрос в том, как сделать так что бы сообщение об отправки выводилось рядом с формой? ..сейчас попробую определить как переменную.

Comment: работает и через определение переменной - $send = mail(...) и без определения - if (mail ...)..

Comment: получается, что бы сообщение об отправке сообщения выводилось не этой же странице, а не странице contact_me.php нужно разместить скрипт на странице с формой?

Comment: Да. И проверять - пришли данные в ПОСТе или нет

Answer (score 0):

Если письма приходят - нужно включить вывод ошибок на страницу и посмотреть, не падает ли mail() после отправки письма, не успев ничего вернутть. Поставьте в начало скрипта ini_set('display_errors',1);

Comment: но письмо же отправляется и приходит на почту..

Comment: Тогда одно объяснение: mail() отправляет письмо, но на чём-тьо спотыкается и ничего не выводит. Нужно включить вывод ошибок на страницу

Comment: пытался вывести ошибку путем внесения изменения .htaccess но ничего не увидел(

Comment: ini_set('display_errors',1); //В начало скрипта